# How can I enable RTW88_8723Du driver when realtek sub options aren't being shown in Menuconfig

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I am building linux kernel 6.3 with localyesconfig. Then, I am trying to enable

`CONFIG_RTW88_8723DU=y` or `CONFIG_RTW88_8723DU=m`

When running menuconfig i can see the option to enable in

Linux Kernel
Device Drivers
Networking device support
Wireless Lan
Realtek 802.11ac wireless chips

[Here in the option to config](https://www.kernelconfig.io/CONFIG_RTW88_8723DU?q=rtw88_8723du&kernelversion=6.3-rc7&arch=x86)

The Realtek 802.11ac wireless chips support doesnt appear

When I edit the .config manually `make menuconfig` resets them after re running menuconfig

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the module was calling an unmet dependency

`CONFIG_CFG80211=y CONFIG_MAC80211=y`

I had to edit the config with all [dependencies](https://www.kernelconfig.io/CONFIG_RTW88_8723DU?kernelversion=6.3-rc7#depends) manually until it worked